# React hooks function runs every time when props changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to useMemo first time. I have a function but it has to render only once. It generates a random number. But when props changed it runs again. How should i use the useMemo ? Or should i try something different ?

```
  const userCups = useMemo(() => props.cups, [props.cups]);
  const game = useMemo(() => props.game, [props.game]);

  function getRandomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (41 - 26) + 26);
  }

return (...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useCallback` for function:

```
const getRandomNumber = useCallback(() => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (41 - 26) + 26);
}, []);
```

And create a `randomNumber` use `useMemo`:

```
const randomNumber= useMemo(getRandomNumber, [getRandomNumber]);
```

Comment: I tried this one but still generates a new number when props changed

Comment: You said useMemo in your answer but u used useCallback in both. I couldnt understand sorry :(

Comment: Create a new variable instead call `getRandomNumber()` directly

Comment: I tried to create new variable but im getting 'Cannot access 'getRandomNumber' before initialization' error this time.

Comment: The second example should use `useMemo` instead of `useCallback`, e.g. `const randomNumber = useMemo(getRandomNumber, [getRandomNumber])`. Or just `const randomNumber = useMemo(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * (41 - 26) + 26), [])`.

Comment: @Gunsela92 move `getRandomNumber` before create new variable